# Knowing$\sum a_{k}$ converges, how to prove that $\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} n a_{n}=0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_{n}$ be decreasing and positive. Then $\sum a_{k}$ converges implies
$\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} n a_{n}=0$.

I think since $na_n$ is positive, the only thing to do is to find an upper bound for the sequence. But I don't know how to split the sequence to form the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$. By Cauchy there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$a_{p+1}+a_{p+2}+...+a_{p+n} < \epsilon/2$$

for $n,p \ge N.$

Since $(a_n)$ is decreasing, it follows that

$$n a_{p+n} <\epsilon/2$$

for $n,p \ge N.$

Hence

$$2n a_{p+n} <\epsilon$$

for $n,p \ge N.$

Therefore

$$(N+n)a_{N+n}<\epsilon$$

for $n \ge N.$

Consequence:

$$ka_k < \epsilon$$

for $k \ge 2N.$